# Wrong Controller gets loaded

Tags: zend-framework3

I have the following problem in one of my Zend Framework 3 application. I have in two different modules the same controller name.

```
Module1\Controller\StartController
Module2\Controller\StartController
```

In both *module.config.php* files I have this router configuration:

> ```
> 'router' => [
>     'routes' => [
>         'module1' => [
>             'type'    => Segment::class,
>             'options' => [
>                 'route' => '/module1[/:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
>                 'constraints' => [
>                     'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
>                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
>                     'id'     => '[0-9]+'
>                 ],
>                 'defaults' => [
>                     'controller' => Controller\StartController::class,
>                     'action'     => 'index',
>                 ],
>             ],
>         ],
>     ],  // ROUTES END HERE
> ],
> ```

Now my problem is that *Module2\Controller\StartController* gets loaded when I call */module1/start*. I assume this is because the aliases for the second module get defined later and overwrite the first entry. Is it somehow possible to define a default namespace in the *defaults* section of this array?
Or what would be the proper solution to my problem?

UPDATE:
I added now the two config files to phpfiddle. You can find them here:
http://main.xfiddle.com/ac5762d7/module1.txt
http://main.xfiddle.com/ac5762d7/module2.txt

The problem I am facing is with "garage".

Comment: Have you defined the namespace on top of the module.config.php(eg. namespace Module1;)  Try 'controller' => \Module1\Controller\StartController::class

Comment: Yes, I did. I think the problem is not in this part of the code but rather with the aliases or factories. They seem to be somehow global.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong! But I guess you may be using **same route name** for both modules.

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'module1' => [ // <-- check this name for both modules
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            ....
        ],
    ],
],
```

Generally ZF3 loads those routes in **LIFO** (Last in First out) **order**. Therefore, routes that **match most often** should be registered **LAST** and least common routes first.

You may try changing modules name to understand the route stack when they get merged in your `config/modules.config.php`

```
return [
    ....

    'Module2',
    'Module1',
];
```

As **Module2** gets merged first so **Module1's** route should work first(in this specific case, for example) while using same route name for both modules. The **LIFO** order.

**EDITED:**

Do not use the same name for creating service name or alias. Using Fully Qualified Class Name is preferable in this case. Try using a unique name for an alias too. Try with factories for controllers as the following:

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\StartController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

ZF3 provides this `InvokableFactory::class` for generation of controllers when needed. But it should not be applicable if any controller has constructor or takes arguments in the constructor. You then must create factory for that type of controllers.

Hope this would help you a bit!

Comment: Thanks. But sadly no. The two routes have different names ("management" and "basedata" in my case). And I think that changing the modules order will only get me the reverse that always the other Controller is loaded in both cases.

Comment: Are they're invokables or factory driven controlles? If factory driver controllers, are you sure about factories?   I'm sure we can find what's wrong if you can share your config files.

Comment: Changing modules order gives just you the sense of aggregating and calling routes by ZF3, but nothing else, if you are using composer for autoloading modules. However, you should check namespaces of both modules. Would you show off more code including namespaces of your script?

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ At the moment I use aliases which point then to factories. And I could imagine that the aliases are the problem because maybe they are somehow global. I will share some more code in a minute. Maybe someone can then better help.

Comment: Try Different name for each service either general service name or alias service name. You are using "garage" alias for both modules which is not correct way to do this, in this case the last one will be working from the route stack. If you are using ZF3 then try with my Edited portion of my answer.